# Keras will not allow building a model that has custom layers inside

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, keras-layer

This is my code for a Resnet:

```
class Resnet50(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def RBB(self, input_shape, K):
        inputs = keras.Input(input_shape)
        X = layers.Conv2D(K, kernel_size=(1, 1), activation="relu")(inputs)
        X = layers.Conv2D(K, kernel_size=(1, 1), activation="relu")(X)
        X = layers.Conv2D(K, kernel_size=(1, 1), activation="relu")(X)
        skip_conn = inputs + X
        output = keras.activations.relu(skip_conn)
        model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
        return model

    def complete_network(self, input_shape, RBB=RBB):
        inputs = keras.Input(input_shape)
        X = layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu")(inputs)
        X = layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu")(X)
        X = RBB(K=64)(X)
        X = RBB(K=64)(X)
        X = RBB(K=64)(X)
        X = RBB(K=128)(X)
        X = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(X)
        X = RBB(K=128)(X)
        X = RBB(K=128)(X)
        X = RBB(K=128)(X)
        X = RBB(K=256)(X)
        X = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(X)    
        X = RBB(K=256)(X)
        X = RBB(K=256)(X)
        X = RBB(K=256)(X)
        X = RBB(K=256)(X)
        X = RBB(K=256)(X)
        X = RBB(K=512)(X)
        X = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(X)  
        X = RBB(K=512)(X)
        X = RBB(K=512)(X)
        X = layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(X)
        X = layers.Flatten()(X)
        X = layers.Dense(1056)(X)
        output = layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")
        model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
        return model

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.complete_network(inputs)
        return x

net = Resnet50()
net.build(input_shape=(224,224))

net.summary()
```

And this is the error when I run the summary operation:

```
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError            Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in build(self, input_shape)
    439         try:
--> 440           self.call(x, **kwargs)
    441         except (tf.errors.InvalidArgumentError, TypeError) as e:

5 frames

OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in build(self, input_shape)
    440           self.call(x, **kwargs)
    441         except (tf.errors.InvalidArgumentError, TypeError) as e:
--> 442           raise ValueError('You cannot build your model by calling `build` '
    443                            'if your layers do not support float type inputs. '
    444                            'Instead, in order to instantiate and build your '

ValueError: You cannot build your model by calling `build` if your layers do not support float type inputs. Instead, in order to instantiate and build your model, call your model on real tensor data (of the correct dtype).

The actual error from `call` is: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function..
```

Any idea on how I can fix this code?

Comment: What tutorial are you using for this model?

Comment: Tutorial ? I just wrote it.

Comment: What is your source? Or did you just make up everything?

Comment: My source is a paper (for the architecture). Then I searched for how to nest 1 module within another. In any case, this should work, but there is some mistake that I just can't figure out.

Comment: There are multiple mistakes including dimensionality problems..that is why I was asking what is your source

Comment: @AloneTogether , paper source is this: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0168169917312619?casa_token=kyMzs3l-gX4AAAAA:ztJs89yYMAAt3L4alAj_T2xPAVVyhJlhY89s7in4qT3tFqrxCh7Qozy5iCmU4XSJ6V2r6rZPP5A                       

I tried to copy-paste exactly the architecture they describe.

Comment: Your `call` function is returning a model. It should return the _output_ of this model instead. There is also no reason to write this model via subclassing, just use the functional API directly.

Comment: There are a lot of issues here, your call is not returning a value but a model, inside call you are passing the input data as the input_shape (which is incorrect), and your custom layer is also not implemented correctly, you are not passing an input_shape to the RBB function, so not sure how this code  is actually running. I suggest you completely rewrite without using the Model subclassing API.

Comment: Also not sure which RBB function is being called, since to call RBB you should be using self.RBB which is not in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building many models inside a model, and creating a model inside a call, and creating tensors without keras layers. All of this is very weird and the problem could be anywhere.

(Well... you can create models inside models, but the rest is too strange)

Just build a single model with keras layers and that's it:

```
def skipFunc(inputs):
    return inputs[0] + inputs[1]       

def RBB(inputTensor, K):
    X = layers.Conv2D(K, kernel_size=(1, 1), activation="relu")(inputTensor)
    X = layers.Conv2D(K, kernel_size=(1, 1), activation="relu")(X)
    X = layers.Conv2D(K, kernel_size=(1, 1), activation="relu")(X)
    
    skip_conn = layers.Lambda(skipFunc)([X, inputTensor])
    output = layers.Activation("relu")(skip_conn)
    
    return output


def complete_network(input_shape, RBB=RBB):
    inputs = keras.Input(input_shape)
    X = layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu")(inputs)
    X = layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu")(X)
    X = RBB(X, K=64)
    X = RBB(X, K=64)
    X = RBB(X, K=64)
    X = RBB(X, K=128)
    X = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(X)
    X = RBB(X, K=128)
    X = RBB(X, K=128)
    X = RBB(X, K=128)
    X = RBB(X, K=256)
    X = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(X)    
    X = RBB(X, K=256)
    X = RBB(X, K=256)
    X = RBB(X, K=256)
    X = RBB(X, K=256)
    X = RBB(X, K=256)
    X = RBB(X, K=512)
    X = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(X)  
    X = RBB(X, K=512)
    X = RBB(X, K=512)
    X = layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(X)
    X = layers.Flatten()
    X = layers.Dense(1056)
    output = layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
    return model

net = complete_network(input_shape=(224,224))
net.summary()
```

Comment: ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv2d_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 224, 224)

Comment: Because your input doesn't have the right shape for a conv 2d later. It says the input needs 4 dimensions and it has only 3. You need an extra dimension in your input. Usually, rgb images would be (None,224,224,3) and BW images would be (None,224,224,1).